# Android Studio Auto Format Settings

Tags: android-studio

anyone knows how to keep this coding format when using auto format (ctrl + shift + f) in Android studio? I just tried numerous settings in preferences but no luck.

[image]

Comment: save this as your customized settings in android studio

Comment: Yes but how can I actually do that with this format?

Comment: you have to refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26182141/6630837

Comment: The first comment to this is pitiful... Thank you Sudheesh R, great link that is exactly what I needed