# Kotlin comment formatting Automatically wrap with previous line in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, formatting

When press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> formatting, Code will change from CodeA to CodeB.
Can I keep the CodeA without automatically new line?

CodeA:

```
object Constant {
    /** http request successful */
    const val HTTP_SUC = 1
    /** http request failed  */
    const val HTTP_ERR = -1
    /** No line breaks above  */
    const val TEST = 0
}
```

CodeB:

```
object Constant {
    /** http request successful */
    const val HTTP_SUC = 1

    /** http request failed  */
    const val HTTP_ERR = -1

    /** There is a new line on it  */
    const val TEST = 0
}
```

Comment: You should try - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181548/how-to-create-my-own-reformat-code-style-in-android-studio

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create my own 'Reformat Code' style in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181548/how-to-create-my-own-reformat-code-style-in-android-studio)

Comment: I tried many configuration items.(Settings > Code Sytle > Java/Kotlin > warpping and Braces/JavaDoc) no problem with java but kotlin has. So I raise this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a long time but maybe someone else stumbles upon this.

Currently Android Studio has such preference to set any number of lines to put before a comment or an annotation line.
Please go to File> Settings> Editor> Code Style> Kotlin then go to "Blank Lines" tab and at the below "Minimum Blank Lines" section, type "0" for the "Before declaration with comment or annotation" option.

Additionally you can check "Keep when reformatting"> "Line Breaks" from the "Wrapping and Braces" tab to keep your manual lines.

Answer (score 1):

No, If you want not to have extra line, you should do it manually. When you use shortcut for doing so, you will have extra line.